# Sample or Demo SWIFT code using FLAnimatedImage

Tags: ios, swift, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to incorporate FLAnimatedImage in my Swift-based iOS application for the purposes of displaying an animated GIF.

I started my importing the `FLAnimatedImage.h` and `FLAnimatedImageView.m` files and  created the `Bridging-Header.h` without issue.

I tried to load the Gif into my ImageView with this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var animatedImageView: FLAnimatedImageView! = animatedImageView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: NSData(contentsOfFile: "chicken.gif")) `
```

But it fails at application startup with the following error code:

> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setAnimatedImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e3c820'

Any suggestion on how to fix the above error?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var gifView: FLAnimatedImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  print("\(gifView)")
  if let path =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("rock", ofType: "gif") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
      let gif = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: data)
      gifView.animatedImage = gif
    }
  }
}
}
```

By the way, did you make your `animatedImageView` in the storyboard subclassed from FLAnimatedImageView?

Comment: How would you do this with a web url. I tried putting it in where you put "rock", its not working. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:
Gif URL Example

```
@IBOutlet weak var gifImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

private func showGifImage(url: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        do {
            let gifData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.gifImageView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(gifData: gifData)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5: gif asset solution

```swift
extension FLAnimatedImage {
    convenience init (gifResource: String) {
        if let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: gifResource, withExtension: "gif"),
           let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) {
            self.init(animatedGIFData: imageData)
        }
        else { 
            self.init(animatedGIFData: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's the best solution but it works for me, please feel free to comment suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following extension:

```
extension FLAnimatedImage {
    convenience init(gifResource: String) {
        self.init(animatedGIFData: NSData(contentsOfFile:     NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(gifResource, ofType: "")!))
    }
}
```

Declaration:

```
@IBOutlet weak var animatedImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!
```

Call:

```
animatedImageView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(gifResource: "chicken.gif")
```

And in the storyboard, the UIImageView has a custom subclass: `FLAnimatedImageView`

Comment: You're right but do clean up a bit. Here's how to initialize for those wondering: `let animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(GIFData: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example", ofType: "gif")!)))`