# Failed to animate gif using SDWebImage in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, sdwebimage

Image is loaded but failed to animate gif

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let urlpath:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "gif")!
    let url   = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlpath)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.sd_animatedGIF(with: data)
    loaderImage.image = image

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "play", withExtension: "gif")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.image.sd_setImage(with: url!)
        }

        let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "play", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let advTimeGif = UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData!)
        let imageView2 = UIImageView(image: advTimeGif)
        imageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 420.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height: 150.0)
        view.addSubview(imageView2)
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do this with a web url. I tried putting it in where you put "play", its not working. Thanks

Comment: @BenAkin NSData *gifImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pariseurl]]; this code is in Objective c but you can get the idea where to get gifImageUrl to data

Answer (score 2):

If there is a requirement to stick with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), then I would note that (as mentioned in the [library github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#animated-images-gif-support)):

> **Animated Images (GIF) support**
>
> - Starting with the 4.0 version, we *rely* on [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) to take 
>     care of our animated images.
>
>   ...
> - To use it, simply make sure you use **FLAnimatedImageView** instead of
>     UIImageView.

**FLAnimatedImage:**

For a simple code to use it in Swift, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217510/sample-or-demo-swift-code-using-flanimatedimage)

Comment: How would you do this with a web url. Thanks